# ImageView taking too much vertical space

Tags: android, android-layout

i am working on a project with a [staggered gridview](https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid) that can support varying height for each nested view,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/layout_border"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

as you can see in the pictures, for wide images the ImageView takes too much vertical space,
this seems to not be an issue for narrow pictures,
 how do i fix this?
[image: Vertical] [image: Horizontal]

Comment: android:scaleType="fitXY"

Comment: i am not trying to re-scale the photo or crop it, i am trying to get rid of the whitespace below and above the picture, that space is a part of Imageview (i put a background to it to make sure)

Comment: why u not use this view avaliable on lib <com.etsy.android.grid.util.DynamicHeightTextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_line1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"/>

Comment: the TextView isnt taking up extrta space(textView's background is blue), the offender is ImageView

Comment: Have u check this https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridViewDemo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as [Naveen Tamrakar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1563038/naveen-tamrakar) suggested,
in [StaggeredGridViewDemo](https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridViewDemo) they extended ImageView with the class "ScaleImageView"
that solved the problem (not really sure what the problem is and why ImageView  isnt wrapping around the image, but that's the solution)

Answer (score 26):

It's been a while, but for those who are dealing with this kind of problem right now: `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` should do the trick!

Comment: This solved my problem! Thank you, had to search a long time to find this. I just added the `adjustViewBounds="true"` to the `ImageView`

Comment: So simple for something that took so long to solve. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and I resolved it by overriding `onMeasure` method of `RelativeLayout`.

```
package com.etsy.android.grid.util;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class DynamicHeightRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout {

    public DynamicHeightRelativeLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public DynamicHeightRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public DynamicHeightRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

        // Hack - This causes the height of RelativeLayout to match
        //        it's content when RelativeLayout is shown in StaggeredGridView. 
        heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }

}
```

Then I used this class in XML layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.etsy.android.grid.util.DynamicHeightRelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ... />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ... />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ... />

</com.etsy.android.grid.util.DynamicHeightRelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use the [ScaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) property..like this:

```
 android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

There are several other types..just pick the one that fits best with your requirement.

Comment: none fits, i need to keep the picture the same (ratio, no cropping) and get rid of the vertical whitespace

Comment: you can't really do it without 'scaleType', unless if you want the box to assume the same form of the image (same aspect ratio).

Comment: Use FrameLayout instead of LinearLayout..this will make the Text be on top of the image instead of below..by doing it, the extenal box will surround the image...you then can later use 'gravity' to align the text to the bottom.